# Putting ImageView in front of other elements < 21API

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView` placed inside a `RelativeView`, and I want this image to be overlapping another `RelativeView` that meets in the middle of the screen. However, whenever I do this only half of the image is being displayed because it is beneath the `RelativeView` it is overlapping.

I know that `android:elevation` and translationZ exist, but those are only for 21+ API's. I am wondering if there is a way to do this with an API lower than 21

[image]

As you can see it is showing in the `RelativeView` it is has been placed in, but is beneath the other `RelativeView`

This is the code to my `.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_inference"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorCoral">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1circle1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1circle2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="141dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="153dp"
            android:background="@drawable/trackbox" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="139dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="139dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="137dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="137dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernamep1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="156dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:translationZ="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-65dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/spinner" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernamep2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="253dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="156dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1circle4"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/p1circle3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1circle3"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="154dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="154dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="154dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="154dp"
            android:background="@drawable/trackbox" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="138dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="138dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="138dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="138dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the `ImageView` in question is labeled as `spinner`

Comment: Didn't understand your problem clearly especially the output you want to show in the screen. However, translationZ is just for elevation and I don't think will help here.

Comment: @Killer yeah I am aware that translationZ won't work. I want the image to be displayed on top of every other element in the screen, but as you can see from the picture, only half of it is being displayed because the RelativeView beneath it is overlapping it

Comment: Prior to Lollipop, the visual z-order was based solely on the order in which the child `View`s are added to the parent. Whichever `View` you want on top will need to be listed last within its parent in the layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,I think the problem is you use the LinearLayout to contain two RelativeLayout and set each weight of them equals to 1 that they would never be overlapped。